# DNS Lookup for "d2e24t2jgcnor2.webhostoid.com" failed. No such host is known

Tags: windows, firefox

this is what comes up in the address bar when you enter any url

http://d2e24t2jgcnor2.webhostoid.com/Secure/Error?URL=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&ResponseCode=502&user_id=1281ef14-4f45-433e-beaa-2a52eb560530&uc=20140914&subid=20140914&source=browsersafeguard-rockettab-spigot-ytd&version=1.0.5368.12608&implementation_id=browsersafeguard-rockettab-spigot-ytd&block_host=False&reg=False&redirectms=True

Comment: Have you tried other browsers? Can you load CMD from start > run and type ping www.bbc.co.uk what do you get back as a response?

Comment: i've done that and am getting the reply packets:sent=4, received=4, lost=0.all the browsers are giving me the same message

Comment: Ok so your getting inbound and outbound traffic and does the IP address for www.bbc.co.uk look something like 212.58.244.67? (its clustered so might be a little different but in that range).. Have you scanned your machine for malware, viruses, spyware, etc.?

Comment: the ip is 212.58.246.91. i run a virus scan last week and it was ok

Comment: Yeah that looks fine correct IP range.. If you go to control panel > Internet Options > Connections TAB > LAN settings > anything set in here? Sometimes Spyware and Malware can set a proxy in here to trap your internet browsing..

Comment: nope there is nothing there.everything is unchecked apart from the chechbox of proxy server

Comment: What do you mean apart from the checkbox of proxy server? Do you use a proxy server?

Comment: i don't think so.but that checkbox is checked.should i uncheck it?

Comment: Yeah un-tick that box then close all web browsers and try again...

Comment: thanks charles.it has worked. it has been stressing me all day.i oweu one

Comment: Excellent I'll put it down as an answer below and if you could mark as a correct answer it would appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your internet options untick all Proxy settings that could be ticked within the Connections > Lan Settings...

*Please see comments above for more information*

Comment: Would've added a comment to your answer CharlesH, however your answer worked, further information is that I think "Rockettab" is the cause for this. It bills itself as a "local search enhancer".

Answer (score 1):

I found that this is adware that has installed itself as a proxy server on 127.0.0.1:49269.  It runs under Windows services with the name Service.exe. So remove the program shown below or disable the proxy in Windows network settings.

This adware has different names.  The malformed URL below shows the two ways the adware throws the DNS lookup error in the browser.  The first shows that the name of the adware is GeniusBox. The second is the error as it appear in this Superuser.com question.

https://www.google.cl/search?q=%5BGeniusBox%5D+DNS+Lookup+for+%22d2e24t2jgcnor2.webhostoid.com%22+failed.+No+such+host+is+known&oq=%5BGeniusBox%5D+DNS+Lookup+for+%22d2e24t2jgcnor2.webhostoid.com%22+failed.+No+such+host+is+known&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8

http://d2e24t2jgcnor2.webhostoid.com/Secure/Error?URL=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.elmercurio.com%2F&ResponseCode=502&user_id=b0a35242-5369-4b70-ab4c-e58f60b376bc&uc=20141218&subid=20141218&source=&version=1.0.5463.19915&implementation_id=geniusbox-spigot&block_host=False&reg=False&redirectms=True&process=chrome

I also wrote to the registrar of the domain webhostoid.com to tell them that someone is is using malware to redirect there.  Here is what they told me. They still have the responsibility to deal with this person.

"This subject domain is using Tucows whois privacy protection and is not owned by Tucows, nor does Tucows provide any hosting or provide bandwidth."

Comment: I found the [GeniusBox adware bundled with Vuze 5.5.0.0](http://support.moonpoint.com/network/proxy/GeniusBox/). Not only did it install itself as a proxy server (the port it uses varies and can change when the system is rebooted) intercepting both HTTP and HTTPS traffic, but it also installs a trusted root certificate, so it can intercept HTTPS traffic without the user receiving any warning that there is a "man-in-the-middle" on the system eavesdropping on HTTPS traffic. I noticed it when I mistyped a site's address and saw a page displayed referencing d2e24t2jgcnor2.webhostoid.com.

Comment: The company associated with the GeniusuBox adware is   GeniusBox/Wisconsin Technology Group in 
Milwaukee, Wisconsin; the information is from [their Terms of Service](http://support.moonpoint.com/network/p2p/vuze/adware.php). The GeniusBox adware uses software from JoltLogic, a company in Kansas City, Missouri.